# Vector Float 3 in SpriteKit

Tags: sprite-kit, swift2

What do you put into

```
SKFieldNode.linearGravityFieldWithVector(???)
```

The documentation calls for a `vector_float3`. How do you make one of those?

Comment: Did you try using `vector_float3(0,0,1)` as the argument?

Comment: Yes. Thank you a ton. I can't believe I didn't think of that. I kept trying to use `vector3(0,0,1)`